# Key modifier error on creation of qApplication

Tags: qt, qapplication

In a Qt app, on execution of `QApplication a(argc, argv);`, the following error appears in the console output:

```
Error:    Key "<MDSW>" added to modifier map for multiple modifiers; Using Mod3, ignoring Mod5
```

Howerver the execution does not seem to be affected.

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?